# Codeigniter - Problem while including env file

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to include .env file  in Codeigniter 3 by following steps:

[integrating.env files in CodeIgniter 3.0 using hooks](http://roopampoddar.com/2016/01/26/integrating-phpdotenv-env-files-in-codeigniter-3-0-using-hooks/)

But, it returns the following error

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: 4096
>
> Message: Argument 1 passed to Dotenv\Dotenv::__construct() must be an
>   instance of Dotenv\Loader, string given, called in
>   /application/config/hooks.php on line 5 and defined
>
> Filename: src/Dotenv.php
>
> Line Number: 31

My /application/config/hooks.php file is configured in the same way as indicated in the tutorial:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$hook['pre_system'] = function() {
    $dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(APPPATH);
    $dotenv->load();
};
```

I had done a quick research and unable to find a perfect solution for the problem occurred, Can you guys please help me to find out a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to install phpdotenv in a different way from the instructions in the first tutorial.
In this tutorial installation is done without the use of Composer:

[PHPDotenv for CodeIgniter (Installation without Composer)](https://github.com/agungjk/phpdotenv-for-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

If you try something like that :

```
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::create(__DIR__);
```

Comment: Hello, Fizik26.  
Thanks for the sugestion!  

I had tried it that way, but it gives the exact same error message.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the vendor folder is in `project/vendor`, not inside `project/application/vendor` folder. Then try this:

```
$hook['pre_system'] = function() {
    $dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::create(FCPATH);
    $dotenv->load();
};
```